# Practical explanation of exponential growth

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

I am presented with the following task:

"There are 100 kids in a kindergarden. At one point, a disease breaks out. Let $y(t)$ be the number of infected children after a time $t$ days. In this scenario, a good model is that the number of infected children in proportional to $y$ and $1 - \frac{y}{100}$. Explain why the logistic equation is a good model for the disease and find an expression for $y(t)$"

I'm having a hard time seeing how I'm supposed to find a general expression for $y(t)$ with the information I'm given.

Comment: I presume they mean you to find a difference/differential equation governing $y$?

Comment: If we use a continuous model, we get $\frac{dy}{dt}=ky\left(1-\frac{y}{100}\right)$. This is a separable DE. It is not the DE of exponential growth.

Comment: We have yet to learn about separable DE in our course, thus I doubt we're supposed to use it.